# Should modern-in-medieval tag be made more generic?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

I just added the modern-in-medieval tag to
[How would a person with modern knowledge of chemistry and medicine fare in Ancient times?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/13748/how-would-a-person-with-modern-knowledge-of-chemistry-and-medicine-fare-in-ancie/13775#13775)

However, the question clearly states that he is interested in modern science set in a time before medieval.  It's not exactly modern individual, just their tech, and it's not limited to medieval times.

I feel the spirit of the tag still applies to the question, but not the literal definition.  It may be worth making the tag a more general concept to include these sort of questions.  At the very least I think the tag should not be limited to medieval times, modern-in-past or something along that lines generalizes the tag so it can be applied in other situations.

As an example I would like to be able to tag my question here: [What would be the impact of a modern programmer and laptop being dropped into World War II, possibly breaking Enigma?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12129/what-would-be-the-impact-of-modern-programer-and-laptop-being-dropped-into-world)

This isn't asking about medieval times, but the idea of modern traveler going to the past still applies, it feels like something closely linked conceptually to the other questions that have the tag, it's a shame that no one can find this question if their interested in other time traveler in the past style stories and click the modern-to-medieval tag (after all this is such a perfect question, having been written so perfectly by a man who is clearly smart, ingenious, and above all the humblest man ever to live).

Comment: Is the general concept here "anachronism"?

Comment: @MonicaCellio perhaps, but I'm not sure I would want to use that as a tag.  When I think anachronism I generally think a *mistaken* addition of something into the wrong time period, that the author forgot that technology xyz didn't exist yet when he wrote his story in time xxx.  It generally has a negative vibe in my mind, though it is accurate.

Comment: Maybe an `item-out-of-time` tag? We'd have to describe a bit what we mean by "item", but it shouldn't carry any negative connotations. There is of course already the `time-travel` tag.

Comment: I agree but I don't have a suggestion. We can just get rid of it!?

Comment: @vincent I think it's not a bad tag, or the concept of it.  I think what we really want is a tag to represent "modern science translated to the past".  These sort of stories are less about using my immediate knowledge of the future to save my grandfather, and about going back to a point where I don't know what will happen immediately and using modern technology and science.  I think a tag that explicitly specified modern technology/science, rather then the traveler himself, as the key driving force of the story is worth having.

Comment: I agree, I think we need one that is a little more generic, I was going to add it the same question but stopped because medieval isn't ancient.  I do think we need a tag for this

Answer (score 3):

Wouldn't the correct answer here be a combination of tags?  for example [time-travel](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel) and [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval) for example

Or [alternate-history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history) and [medieval](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medieval)

I think this makes more sense than a single tag for a particularly narrow concept.